# Using .bind() "this" on AddEventListener?

Tags: javascript

I'm practicing a little Javascript and can't for the life of me figure out how to bind "this" with an event handler...

Below is my code. I'm trying to make it so that the color of whichever button is clicked will turn red. But only the first button turns red.

```
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>

var change = function() {
  this.style.color = "red";
}

var button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", change, false);
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: `this` is bind automatically to the element in an event handler. You'r problem is, that `querySelector` returns a single element only. You'd need `querySelectorAll`  and a then iterate through the returned elements and attach the event to each element.

Comment: u can also use 'document.getElementsByTagName("button")'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could apply the style to all buttons with [`Element#querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)

```js
var change = function(){
    this.style.color = "red";
}

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

[].forEach.call(buttons, function (button) {
    button.addEventListener("click", change, false);
});
```

```html
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
```

Comment: Is there any reason you chose not to use `[].forEach.call(buttons, function (button) { ... })`?

Comment: thank you. would never have crossed my mind that forEach is needed... if only it's as simple as using $this haha

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you are using querySelector to get a single button

change it to querySelectorAll to get all the buttons and addeventlistener for all the buttons

check this snippet

```js
var change = function() {
  this.style.color = "red";
}
window.onload = function() {
  var button = document.querySelectorAll("button");
  button.forEach(function(element) {

    element.addEventListener("click", change, false);
  });

}
```

```html
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
```

```js
var change = function() {
  this.style.color = 'red';
}
window.onload = function() {
  var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

  for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    button[i].addEventListener('click', change, null);
  }
}
```

```html
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: it does not help. the nodeList is not iterable with forEach

Comment: actually, not on edge.

Comment: And probably other browsers that do not support it _yet_, doesn't make the answer incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

(Consider this only as a possibility of your problem if you don't want to use binding operator)

Here you have a working example with two different inputs and two different elements in javascript:

**HTML:**

```
<button id="button1">1</button>
<button id="button2">2</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var change = function(){
    this.style.color = "red";
}

var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");

button1.addEventListener("click", change, false);
button2.addEventListener("click", change, false);
```

You can find the working code here: https://jsfiddle.net/97807x0f/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Why not just use `document.getElementsByTagName` at the very least? OP's example was shown using `document.querySelector`. It might be better to try to create an example that is closer to that.

Comment: That's right, Nina Scholz example is much more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it like this:

```
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>

<script>
  var change = function(e){
    var e = window.e || e;

    if (e.target.tagName !== 'BUTTON')
        return;


    e.target.style.color = "red";
}

document.addEventListener('click', change, false);
</script>
```

The good part is that it will also work for dynamically added element.
Here's the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/gWOapp6E4hQWdhrm0Z99?p=preview